# Python code written in Sublime Text 3 won't run

Tags: python, terminal, sublimetext3, text-editor

I am trying to run some simple code via my Linux terminal that I wrote in Sublime Text 3.

There is no issue in my code, it looks like the following code:

```
# Some Initialization
while True:
    if (i == 1):
        # Do  something
```

When I run the code via the terminal it won't reach the contents of the `if` statement even when `i == 1` is `True` (I printed and checked that).

Is there some way to configure Sublime Text 3 to fix the issue?

For example, the following code won't enter the `if` statement:

```
i = 1
print(i == 1) # it prints True on the terminal
if (i == 1): # the statement is True but won't enter the statement
    print('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Hi, Can I have that complete part of code, and the description of error you are getting ?

Comment: Are you sure this is because sublime text?

Comment: Right now your code is invalid(`i` isnt defined, theres nothing after the if), mind providing a working example ? Also its very unlikely that your Editor is at fault.

Comment: This is almost certainly not Sublime related; If you were using Sublime to run the code,  all it does is invoke an external `python` interpreter to do the job. On the other hand if you just used Sublime to write it, then the issue is with what you wrote and not the tool that you used to write it.

Comment: I didn't use sublime to run the code as I mentioned I tried to run the file via the terminal. Also this is the full code. If I intialize i with the value i=1 it won't get into the if statement if though when I print just before the statement the follow: print(i==1) and get True

Answer (score 0):

If the error is something regarding the variable `i`, it is because you haven't initialised any value for `i`.

You can initialise `i`:

```
i = 0
```

before starting the `while` loop.

If this is not the case, what is the detailed error message?

Comment: It is not connected to any intialization issue, it won't reach the if statement and won't enter it even when the statement is True. This is an issue with the editor, not the code.

Comment: It can't be the editor if you're running the code from the command-line. Try recreating that exact code in Vim and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing it **inside** sublime text 3 by going to tools>Build System>Python
and then pressing Ctrl+B. I am not a 100% sure since I don't have Linux but this might work